# Compare two dates and compute date difference

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to tables to compare:

**Schedule table:**

[image]

**Official receipt table:**

[image]

I just want to know if the client is paying according to his schedule by comparing the dates between Official receipt and Schedule table. if not, it will give him a penalty of $10 daily by counting the days from scheduled date.

example: the 1st schedule of payment is 2019-11-02. but the OR shows he paid on 2019-12-10. which is 38 days later than his 1st payment schedule. then penalty will be imposed. Any Idea? Thank you.

I want something like this:

```
Loanid     | PaymentSched | Date OR    | Past Due | Penalty
H1807.0008 | 2019-11-02   | 2019-12-10 | 38 Days  | 380
```

Comment: Maybe better to post sample T-SQL code with sample data. But I have Q

How do you link payment to receipt? is it always the 1st date after? 
e.g. how do you know the 2019-12-10 receipt isn't for 2019-12-02? 
and the two 2020-05-30 receipts, it's for 2020-03-02 AND 04-02 payments?
and by this logic, all of them have 30+ day penalty, is that "reasonable"?

I'd think normally there is the INVOICE-PAYMENT (with invoice ID)-receipt (with payment ID) relationship. Then it's easy to calculate

Comment: @JerryHung. It is a monthly payment. if he cant pay for like a month. he will have a 30days penalty.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that there is no missing payment and no partial payment, then one option is to enumerate the scheduled payments and receipts with `row_number()`, then join them together. The rest is is just filtering on late payment and computing the days late and penalty:

```
select 
    s.loan_id,
    s.date_payment,
    r.date_or,
    datediff(day, s.date_payment, r.date_or) as past_due_days,
    10 * datediff(day, s.date_payment, r.date_or) as penalty
from (
    select s.*, row_number() over(partition by loan_id order by date_payment) rn
    from schedule s
    where total_payment > 0
) s
inner join (
    select r.*, row_number() over(partition by loan_id order by date_or) rn
    from official_receipt r
) r on s.loan_id = r.loan_id and s.rn = r.rn and s.total_payment = r.amount
where r.date_or > s.date_payment
```

Answer (score 0):

datediff will help you

```sql
select datediff(day,'2019-10-02','2019-12-10')

select [Loanid],[PaymentSched],[Date OR],datediff(day,[PaymentSched],[Date OR]) as [Past Due],datediff(day,[PaymentSched],[Date OR])*10 as Penalty
from Schedule s
join [Official receipt] o on o.[Loanid]=s.[Loanid]
```

Comment: This would result in a cross-join of both tables, as the load-id will be equal for every row. You would need to ensure you have some sort of mechanism in place to prevent every date in the `schedule` table from being referenced and compared to every date in the `receipt` table.